¿Por qué obtener el tipo de null en JavaScript devuelve "object"?
He estado aprendiendo JavaScript y me encontré con un comportamiento que no entiendo del todo.   Cuando trato de obtener el tipo de null usando el operador typeof, me devuelve "object"

Es un bug que existe desde las primeras implementaciones de JavaScript, y no se ha arreglado por miedo a romper la base de codigo existente: tenes mas informacion aca


null es un valor primitivo, un valor primitivo puede definirse como algo que no es un objeto

Pero a su vez, es un valor valido para un objeto, solo los objetos pueden ser null, no así los primitivos


Y aquí comienza el lio:
Javascript para almacenar un valor utilizaba 32 bit, de los cuales 1 o 3 bits eran determinar su tipo

000: Objeto
1: int
010: doble
100: String
110: Booleano

Adicional a esto se, estableció que null seria todos ceros (32 ceros).
Ejemplo:
Estos 3 indica que es un booleano
↓↓↓
11010101010101... 

Estos 3 indica que es un objeto
↓↓↓
00010101010101... 

El nulo seria (32 ceros)
00000000000000...

Y como el null comienza con 3 ceros al igual que Object. Al evaluar el tipo de dato de almacenado en memoria, resulta que para null obtienes Object
Yo considero que esto fue intencional, dado que solo un Object puede ser null, tiene sentido representar el null como 32 ceros, incluyendo los 3 ceros que indican su tipo (pero son suposiciones mía)
El tema es que se creó una función llamada JSVAL_IS_OBJECT(valor), la cual retornaba:

true Si era objeto
true Si era null (por las razones antes mencionadas)
false En cualquier otro caso

Y esta función se utiliza para la función typeof, la cual se veía así:
voy a simplificar la función, pero dejo la original abajo
JS_TypeOfValue(jsval v) {
 JSType type = JSTYPE_VOID;

 if (JSVAL_IS_OBJECT(v)) { // Esta es la función que da el problema, aquí entra aun cuando es null
    
    if ( ¿es una función? ){ // aquí NO entra
      type = JSTYPE_FUNCTION;
    } 
    else { //aquí entra
      type = JSTYPE_OBJECT; //<-- Y aquí establece que es del tipo object!!!!
    }
 }
  //otros if para deteterminar si es numero, string, etc
  return type;
}



JS_TypeOfValue(JSContext * cx, jsval v) {
  JSType type = JSTYPE_VOID;
  JSObject * obj;
  JSObjectOps * ops;
  JSClass * clasp;

  CHECK_REQUEST(cx);
  if (JSVAL_IS_VOID(v)) { // No es void, aquí no entra
    type = JSTYPE_VOID;
  } else if (JSVAL_IS_OBJECT(v)) { // Aquí entra, porque si un valor es null, debe de ser un objeto
    obj = JSVAL_TO_OBJECT(v);
    //no entra en este if
    if (obj &&
      (ops = obj - > map - > ops,
        ops == & js_ObjectOps ?
        (clasp = OBJ_GET_CLASS(cx, obj),
          clasp - > call || clasp == & js_FunctionClass)
        :
        ops - > call != 0)) { 
      type = JSTYPE_FUNCTION;
    } else { //aqui entra
      type = JSTYPE_OBJECT; //<-- Y aquí asigna que es del tipo object!!!!
    }
  } else if (JSVAL_IS_NUMBER(v)) {
    type = JSTYPE_NUMBER;
  } else if (JSVAL_IS_STRING(v)) {
    type = JSTYPE_STRING;
  } else if (JSVAL_IS_BOOLEAN(v)) {
    type = JSTYPE_BOOLEAN;
  }
  return type;
}



Entonces: ¿Por qué obtener el tipo de null en JavaScript devuelve "object"?
Porque:

JSVAL_IS_OBJECT retorna true cuando el valor es null
JS_TypeOfValue No cuenta con alguna condición que evalue estos casos algo como if(v==null) hubiera bastado

Referencia

Esta es una especificación de ECMAScript mantenida por razones de compatibilidad con navegadores más antiguos.
Y null no es un objeto sino un valor especial con su propio significado.


objNOT = null

objREAL ={
  m: "xxx"
}

obj  = objREAL

if (objNOT instanceof Object) {
  console.log("Es un objeto")
} else {
 console.log("No es un objeto")
}



null es un valor primitivo que representa la ausencia de valor , pero no es un objeto en sí.
